# Ive been trying to get this to start in the center of the screen

Tags: java, swing, jframe

This is JavaSE-11 because i think its the latest LTS version of java and im using eclipse IDE.
Please somebody tell me how to get this to the center of the screen on run.

```
package Main;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Toolkit;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class GUI extends JFrame{
    
    protected static final ImageIcon ICON = new ImageIcon("Image.png");

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new GUI();
    }

    public GUI(){
        Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(dim.width/2-this.getSize().width/2, dim.height/2-this.getSize().height/2));
        setTitle("GUI");
        setIconImage(ICON.getImage());
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't extend JFrame. You only extend a component when you add functionality to the component. Adding components to the frame does not add functionality. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Labels](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html). The `LabelDemo` example will show how to better structure your code so you don't need to extend JFrame.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
frame.setLocationRelativeTo( null );
```

AFTER the size of the frame has been determined.

So, The basic structure for the code should be:

```
frame.add(...);
frame.pack();
frame.setLocationRelativeTo( null );
frame.setVisible( true );
```

Answer (score -1):

```
        int w = this.getPreferredSize().width/2;
        int y = this.getPreferredSize().height/2;
        int dimw = dim.width/2;
        int dimh = dim.height/2;
        setLocation( dimw-w, dimh-y);
```